Measure real corona discharge intensity, range 2000-7500V?
I need to measure the actual corona discharge intensity produced by a particular circuit and electrode array. I'd love numbers as hard as possible, though am not sure what units apply; alternatively, a qualitative number relative to that produced by an available test standard will do. The test standard takes in 0.05A at 12VDC and outputs discharge at 5000V; the new circuit is variable, max being 1A in and 11kV discharge, but I won't be using higher than 7.5kV discharge.
Thus far research seems to indicate that appropriate UV detection may be the lowest-hanging-fruit method, but I haven't found hard data as to wavelengths and sensitivity needed. Anyone have a solid direction to go? This is a low-budget project, I do not have institutional resources to use at this time.

What exactly do you mean by "discharge intensity"? Are you looking for a current measurement, a voltage measurement, a field strength measurement or something else?

I'm guessing this has something to do with your engine project.

Good guess :-)  The challenge really is to find a way to come as close as possible to measuring negative ion output.  I have a meter now, but like all of them on the market less than a grand, its precision is quite low, +/- 25%.  I also need a wider range than my meter can handle, because I'm trying to find a way to safely use a component which appears to be able to deliver 20x the output of the ones I have been using.  So I've been studying principles, and ran into UV detection as one possible method.
